# Only one callback may be registered. Shows this error for Expo Appload

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, expo

Here is an immage of the error I get:

[image: Here is the image of an error.]
I want to change splash screen of my app and trying to use Expo Appload. when I added it on my app.js it shows this error. How can Isolve this error? Here is my code.

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View,ScrollView,Image,Icon } from 'react-native';
import {
  Asset,
  AppLoading,
} from 'expo';


import WelcomeScreen from './screens/WelcomeScreen';
import SigninScreen from './screens/SigninScreen';
import SignupScreen from './screens/SignupScreen';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import BusinessScreen from './screens/BusinessScreen';
import ProfileScreen from './screens/ProfileScreen';
import SettingsScreen from './screens/SettingsScreen';
import ContactScreen from './screens/ContactScreen';
import ForgetpassScreen from './screens/ForgetpassScreen';
import { TabNavigator, DrawerNavigator, StackNavigator,contentOptions} from 'react-navigation';
import DrawerContent from './components/DrawerContent'


export default class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    isReady: false,
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this._cacheResourcesAsync();
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isReady) {
      return <AppLoading />;
    }

    return (
      <View>
        <Image source={require('./assets/images/expo-icon.png')} />
        <Image source={require('./assets/images/slack-icon.png')} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  async _cacheResourcesAsync() {
    const images = [
      require('./assets/images/expo-icon.png'),
      require('./assets/images/slack-icon.png'),
    ];

    for (let image of images) {
      await Asset.fromModule(image).downloadAsync();
    }

    this.setState({isReady: true});
  }
}





const MainNavigator = TabNavigator({

  Welcome: { screen: WelcomeScreen },

  Signin: { screen: SigninScreen },

  Signup: { screen: SignupScreen },

  main: {
       screen: DrawerNavigator({
         Home: { screen: HomeScreen },

         Business: { screen: BusinessScreen },

         Profile : { screen: ProfileScreen },
         Settings : {screen: SettingsScreen},
         Contact: {screen:ContactScreen},
       },
       {
   drawerPosition: 'Left',

           contentComponent: props => <ScrollView>< DrawerContent {...props} /></ScrollView>,
           contentOptions: {
        inactiveTintColor: '#1414fc',
        activeBackgroundColor: '#383838',
        activeTintColor: '#1414fc',

       }

      }

    ),
      forget  : {
             screen: StackNavigator({
               Forgetpass:{screen: ForgetpassScreen},

             },
           )
         }
     }
   },

   );


return (
  <MainNavigator />



);


}
}
```

How can this problem be solved? The link of documentation of Expo Apploading is [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/app-loading.html).

As you see I am trying to mix it with my customized app.js which includes react-navigation.

Comment: It would make sense to also include the error/backtrace as text inside your post (instead of linking to an image) this makes it easier to find/index your question.

Comment: Streamlined the picture

Answer (score 0):

I was getting that issue when I called two react callbacks in a same function in my native modules.
Removal of any of them works fine for me.

```
 + (void)onOcrResult:(NSString *)result {
   // [myProtocolNew onOcrResult : result];
   [myProtocolNew onOcrFailure : @"UNKNOWN"];
   [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController 
   dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```